# jQuery click event not firing on form submit?

Tags: jquery, html, windows-8

I am not sure what is wrong but every alternate time my click event does not fire. Is there a problem with fadeIn function? I tried changing `.click` to `.live` and `.on` and the same problem arises.

Here is my code:

```
$('#form').submit(function (ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();                
     $('#wrapper').html(html).scrollTop(0);              
     $('#base').fadeIn('slow', function () { 
          document.onkeydown = docOnKeydown; 
     }).click(function () {
          alert('Click Fired');
     });
     return false;
});
```

Comment: @Vega He does call it on `$('#base')`, it's just hard to notice with this way of indenting.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be helpful here.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me but every time you submit, you add a click event HANDLER to `$('#base')` - is this the desire or do you want to FIRE the click event then?

Comment: You should indent a little bit better your code. For me, it is also hard to get, what's your question.

Comment: sorry pasting it here messed it up.

Comment: Sorry for not making my intent clear. After the user hits submit, I present him with a div and I want to listen in on the clicks of the user so I can perform specific actions. I don't want to simulate a click. I just want to handle user's click action. Is this clear?

Comment: Does that div (presummably #base, correct if not) exist on the page just not be displayed or is it rendered/inserted after?

Comment: The div is part of the html and it exists on the page. I just fadeIn and out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you wish to simply add an event handler to the object in question:

```
$('#base').click(function () {
   alert('Click Fired');
}).fadeIn('slow', function () { document.onkeydown = docOnKeydown; });
```

trigger the click event after the fadein?

```
$('#base').fadeIn('slow', function () {
    document.onkeydown = docOnKeydown; 
    $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

trigger click I(potentially while fadein)

```
$('#base').fadeIn('slow', function () {
    document.onkeydown = docOnKeydown; 
 }).trigger('click');
```

EDIT: Just and the handler when the rest is added

```
$(document).on('click','#base',function () {
  alert('Click Fired');
});
$('#form').submit(function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $('#wrapper').html(html).scrollTop(0);
  $('#base').fadeIn('slow', function () {
    document.onkeydown = docOnKeydown;
  });
  return false;
});
```

better: for the handler if the base has a container. tag to that as more "local" than the document for performance reasons.

```
$('#basecontainer').on('click','#base',function () {
  alert('Click Fired');
});
```

EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:, "it exists already" this should also work and be simpler on the DOM:

```
$('#base').click(function () {
  alert('Click Fired');
});
$('#form').submit(function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $('#wrapper').html(html).scrollTop(0);
  $('#base').fadeIn('slow', function () {
    document.onkeydown = docOnKeydown;
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry for not making my intent clear. After the user hits submit, I present him with a div and I want to listen in on the clicks of the user so I can perform specific actions. I don't want to simulate a click. I just want to handle user's click action. Is this clear?

Comment: You were adding the Handler each time a submit took place - you only needed it to be added (the handler) one time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trigger click you should use "trigger" function - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

```
$('#base').fadeIn('slow', function () { document.onkeydown = docOnKeydown; })
            .click(function () {
              alert('Click Fired');
            });
$('#base').trigger('click');
```